# In Asp.net to manage control in table (tr,td) is right or wrong pls suggest?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

In Asp.net to manage control in table (tr,td) is right or wrong pls suggest?
If wrong than what is right for programming purpose pls suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use table elements in asp.net on the server side.

You can also place controls in td tags.

Answer (score 0):

I use tables to manage the layout of my controls if they are representing tabular data. Otherwise I tend to try and use CSS for layout.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I believe it to be right when the attributes of that table need to be dynamic. Such as a certain value range needing to stand out (i.e. if the cell's value is greater than 100, make it bold and red).

If you're application does not require dynamic attributes, there is no need for client-side code to be on your server-side and I would agree with one of the other posters that does it in CSS if he can.